# openssl s_client proving error certificate

Tags: server, proxy, squid

I cannot connect to website https://baohiemxahoi.gov.vn when i use proxy server squid.

On my server i try to connect with openssl :

```
openssl s_client -connect baohiemxahoi.gov.vn:443 -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x55e83d64af50 [0x55e83d65a360] (176 bytes => 176 (0xB0))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 ab 01 00 00-a7 03 03 c9 fa 00 a9 51   ...............Q
0010 - 62 4e 19 a4 ec 8f 93 51-7d f8 4e 59 83 dc a7 c1   bN.....Q}.NY....
0020 - 4a 2f d2 2b 7d d0 08 26-85 89 6d 00 00 38 c0 2c   J/.+}..&..m..8.,
0030 - c0 30 00 9f cc a9 cc a8-cc aa c0 2b c0 2f 00 9e   .0.........+./..
0040 - c0 24 c0 28 00 6b c0 23-c0 27 00 67 c0 0a c0 14   .$.(.k.#.'.g....
0050 - 00 39 c0 09 c0 13 00 33-00 9d 00 9c 00 3d 00 3c   .9.....3.....=.<
0060 - 00 35 00 2f 00 ff 01 00-00 46 00 0b 00 04 03 00   .5./.....F......
0070 - 01 02 00 0a 00 0a 00 08-00 1d 00 17 00 19 00 18   ................
0080 - 00 23 00 00 00 0d 00 20-00 1e 06 01 06 02 06 03   .#..... ........
0090 - 05 01 05 02 05 03 04 01-04 02 04 03 03 01 03 02   ................
00a0 - 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03-00 16 00 00 00 17         ..............
00b0 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x55e83d64af50 [0x55e83d651143] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 176 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1683173129
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

I try to curl :

```
curl -XGET https://baohiemxahoi.gov.vn
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to baohiemxahoi.gov.vn:443
```

Anyone help me please!

I want to try connect this website